# I couldn't find Landsat 5 scene starting from 2002-08-04 to 2008-06-01

Tags: remote-sensing, satellite, geography

I am searching for Landsat 5 TM image from 2000 to 2012 in Earth Explorer Web site (https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/). However, I couldn't find any scene in my study area starting from 2002-08-04 to 2008-06-01. Where do I find those scenes starting from 2002-08-04 to 2008-06-01?

my study area is Central Tigray, Ethiopia; path/row=169/51 and 169/50 or latitude=13.751 and longitude=38.8205

Comment: It would be helpful to know, which your studay area is.

Comment: the study area is central Tigray, Ethiopia. lat=13.751 and long=38.8205. path/row=169/51 and 169/50